# Can't get access to my IIS Server?

Tags: networking, iis, windows-server-2012, private-ip

Before I could get access to my IIS Server using its static private IP address (on the Windows Server 2012 itself), but now I can only access the IIS Server web page using its localhost and 127.0.0.1 addresses?

I binded the static address to the port, but still no access. Firewall allows the port (which was configured before, though its on the Server itself anyway).

Can anyone identify why I can't access the IIS Server within in the Server using its static IP address?

Thanks

Comment: Is something else bound to that port already? (Check with `netstat -abn`)  What error or response information do you get from a browser trying to access the port?  Can you add the output from `netsh http show iplisten` to your question?

Comment: Yes your correct. I was using port 8080, which was actually conflicting with Remote Access Management. I changed IIS to listen to it's default port 80, and now it works normal again. Thanks for the input

Comment: Great!  I'll put that in an answer for other people who are searching for the same thing in the future.

Comment: No problem. Glad I got it working again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS's bindings by default are on `0.0.0.0`, so being able to only access them on only `127.0.0.1` could be an indication of a different service already using that listening port (check with `netstat -abn`), which seems to have been the case here.